# JAVA: Having trouble using DecimalFormat? Need 30.40 not 30.4

Tags: java, double

I currently have switch statements that randomly generate a salary based on the title of a worker. Everything works fine but I just can't seem to truncate the salaries correctly.

I need salaries to end with two decimals no matter what. It works with salaries like "57662.24" but I also get salaries like "87756.4" which I need to be "87756.40"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so I'm hoping I can get some help!

```
// Method to return salary based on rank
private static Double salary(String rank) {

    // initialize variables for use in switch statement
    double sal = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

    switch (rank) {
    case "Assistant":
        sal = random.nextDouble() * (80000 - 50000) + 50000;
        break;

    case "Associate":
        sal = random.nextDouble() * (110000 - 60000) + 60000;
        break;

    case "Full":
        sal = random.nextDouble() * (130000 - 75000) + 75000;
        break;
    }
    return sal = Double.valueOf(df.format(sal));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method so that it returns the `String` as formatted by the `DecimalFormat` object.

```
 private static String salary(double sal) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

    return (df.format(sal));
 }
```

You go to the effort of formatting it, then you lose that effort by making it a `Double` again.

Comment: @4castle - Thanks for the edit. It was rather embarrassingly messy.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```